# How to rename multiple file name include subfolders?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, find, xargs

For example i have the following files:

```
./dirA/fileA.png
./dirA/fileB.png
./dirA/fileC.png
./dirB/fileD.png
./dirB/fileE.png
./dirB/dirC/fileF.png
```

Is there any one line command or script to rename the file name to be the following?

```
./dirA/fileA@2x.png
./dirA/fileB@2x.png
./dirA/fileC@2x.png
./dirB/fileD@2x.png
./dirB/fileE@2x.png
./dirB/dirC/fileF@2x.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -type f -name '*.png' -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.png}@2x.png"' Move {} \;
```

- `find .`

  This starts a file search with the current directory.
- `-type f`

  This limits the search to regular files.
- `-name '*.png'`

  This limits the search to files whose names end with `.png`.
- `-execdir bash -c '...' Move {} \;`

  This runs the command in single quotes with `$0` assigned to `Move` and `$1` assigned to the name of the file that was found.  In our case, the command in single quotes is:
- `mv "$1" "${1%.png}@2x.png"`

  This renames the file to end with `@2x.png`.  The construct `${1%.png}` removes the `.png` from the end of the file name.  Thus, `${1%.png}@2x.png` replaces the `.png` at the end of the file name with `@2x.png`.

#### Example

Let's start with directories with these files:

```
$ find .
.
./dirA
./dirA/fileA.png
./dirA/fileC.png
./dirA/fileB.png
./dirB
./dirB/fileE.png
./dirB/dirC
./dirB/dirC/fileF.png
./dirB/fileD.png
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.png' -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.png}@2x.png"' Move {} \;
```

After the command has executed, we now have these files:

```
$ find .
.
./dirA
./dirA/fileC@2x.png
./dirA/fileA@2x.png
./dirA/fileB@2x.png
./dirB
./dirB/dirC
./dirB/dirC/fileF@2x.png
./dirB/fileD@2x.png
./dirB/fileE@2x.png
```